# How to connect to base from sub domain? SQLiteConnector, connectionString

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite, web-config

My web site c# asp.net and SQLite. In main domeine www. MySite. com all work fine in web.config...

```
 <connectionStrings>
        <add name="SQLiteConnector" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|MyBase.db3;" 
providerName="System.Data.SQLite"/>
          </connectionStrings>
```

MyBase.db3 is in App_Data folder.
Now I have web site in domain www. NewSubdomain . MySite .com
And don't know how to make connecton to base in  main domeine www.MySite.com 
What I must put in web.config do I need something more or else to make connection? HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

Since the web.config file is common for all the sites, you can add multiple connection strings like this for each sub domain :

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add connectionString="" name="subdomain1"/>
        <add connectionString="" name="subdomain2"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Then you can check for the current url using

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

Comment: I need connection to only one base. With tihs in main domein www. MySite .com
What to put in connectionString="" ? Some exsample  how <connectionStrings> must look?

Comment: you need to host your sub-domain as an web application on the iis server . And if your keeping one database with both the domain and subdomain then it shouldn't be causing any problem... !